# Eclipse / PyDev overrides @sys, cannot find Python 64bits interpreter

Tags: python, linux, eclipse, pydev

I'm working in a multiuser environment with the following setup:

- Linux 64bits environment (users can login in to different servers).
- Eclipse (IBM Eclipse RSA-RTE) 32bits. So Java VM, Eclipse and PyDev is 32bits.
- Python 3 interpreter is only available for 64bits at this moment.

In the preferences for PyDev, I want to set the path to the Python interpreter like this:

/app/python/@sys/3.2.2/bin/python

In Eclipse/PyDev, *@sys* points to *i386_linux26* even if the system actually is *amd64_linux26*. So if I do not explicitly write *amd64_linux26* instead of *@sys*, PyDev will not be able to find the Python 3 interpreter which is only available for 64bits. The link works as expected outside Eclipse/PyDev, e.g. in the terminal.

Any ideas how to force Eclipse/PyDev to use the real value of *@sys*?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the preferences for PyDev in Eclipse I want to be able set a path to the python interpreter that contains "@sys". I will simplify the path in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really think there's anything that can be done on the PyDev side... it seems @sys is resolved based on the kind of process you're running (not your system), so, if you use a 64 bit vm (I think) it should work...

Other than that, you may have to provide the actual path instead of using @sys...